# Maximum call stack size exceeded even with only 1 iteration

Tags: node.js, while-loop, callstack

My while loop is giving me an error of call stack size exceeded, so I tried to limit it in some ways that did not work and now, I have the following piece:

```
var hasnext = true;
while(hasnext) {
  options.form['formBusca:dataScroller1'] = (++page).toString();

  var request = client.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
    var html = dom.load(body);
    var buttons = html('td.rich-datascr-button');
    if (some_length_condition_that_does_not_matter) {
      hasnext = false;
    }
  });
  process.stdout.write((page).toString() + '\r');
  break;
}
```

If the logic I learned is still the same nowadays, this while should execute once and only once, since its last statement is a break without condition, so it should end after finising the first iteration.

However, this does not work. In some way, I exceed the call stack everytime. Why does it happen, and how can I prevent it from happening?

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Additional information: `client` is the `request` module and `dom` is the `cheerio` module.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an error about the call stack size being exceeded then it's likely a problem with recursion in a function you are calling, not the `while` loop. You are doing an asynchronous `post()` call within the loop and there is probably something recursing in there. You can test by commenting out the whole `post()` block to see if it works, and then commenting out just the code inside the callback. Find where it's actually happening.

The only other possibility is that your call stack is already very deep by the time this code is running and so running normal code like this is exceeding the maximum call stack size. That's easy to test though by just throwing an exception in the loop and seeing how deep your call stack is.

**EDIT**

It looks like you may be using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module by mikeal. I use that all the time. I have no idea what your `dom` variable is referencing though. Depending on what options you are passing in your `post()` call and what `dom.load()` is doing, I could easily see your problem being either of those.

Comment: I added what modules I'm using to the answer. The problem seems to be with the request module, because if I comment it out it works fine, but even if I comment everything inside the callback (so I have `function(error, response, body){}`, I get the stack error.

Comment: What options are you passing to `post()`?

Comment: I uploaded the code [here](https://gist.github.com/ranisalt/56e051a08c9276f8c6ff/b144c2731942302931b25b20fbd08c4681b97ee3) (search for `hasnext`). You may see it is not really too deep by this line, it's less than 10 levels I believe.

Comment: When it gives you the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` is it giving you anything else more useful above that? Maybe something with a file and line number?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Is there something like a "debug mode" with more verbose errors in node?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's something weird with the request module that could be causing your trouble. Regardless, to avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) you might look into using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module. In this case you are probably wanting to use `async.series()`

Comment: How would I implement this? The condition to break the while is when the requested page does not contain a certain DOM element. I can't figure out how to do it with this async package.

Comment: I think I need some way to synchronize those requests, as any of them may be the last one and I keep firing more requests without possibility to check if they are valid.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is actually [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback)